# Move "*" to new column in R

Tags: r, character, gsub, stringr

Hello I have a column in a data.frame, it has many rows, e.g.,

```
df = data.frame("Species" = c("*Briza minor", "*Briza minor", "Wattle"))
```

I want to make a new column "Species_new" where the "*" is moved to the end of the character string, e.g.,

```
df = data.frame("Species" = c("*Briza minor", "*Briza minor", "Wattle"),
            "Species_new" = c("Briza minor*", "Briza minor*", "Wattle"))
```

Is there a way to do this using gsub? The manual example would take far too long as I have approximately 50,000 rows.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You need `sub("^([*])(.*)", "\\2\\1", df$Species)`

Answer (score 3):

One option is to capture the `*` as a group and in the `replacement` reverse the backreferences

```
df$Species_new <- sub("^([*])(.*)$", "\\2\\1", df$Species)
df$Species_new
#[1] "Briza minor*" "Briza minor*" "Wattle"
```

NOTE: `*` is a metacharacter meaning 0 or more, so we can either escape (`\\*`) or place it in brackets (`[]`) to evaluate the raw character i.e. literal evaluation

Answer (score 0):

Thanks so much for the quick response, I also found a workaround;

```
df$Species_new = sub("[*]","",df$Species, perl=TRUE)

differences = setdiff(df$Species,df$Species_new)

tochange = subset(df,df$Species == differences)
toleave = subset(df,!df$Species == differences)

tochange$Species_new = paste(tochange$Species_new, "*", sep = "")

df = rbind(tochange,toleave)
```

Comment: Make sure you don't have `NA`s in `Species` or you will lose rows. You can use `paste0` in stead of `paste` with `sep=""` (same thing, just more readable). but I think you should take @akrun's solution as it's more robust and compact.